# Sending Network Stream from Playlist (.m3u8) to AirPlay?

Tags: itunes, video, appletv, airplay, streaming

I have a Mac, an Apple TV, and I have a network video stream (.../stream.m3u8) that I'd like to send over AirPlay to my Apple TV.

If I open it in QuickTime/VLC, it plays great, but neither support streaming *video* over AirPlay.

And when I try to open the stream in iTunes, it instead adds it as a playlist, instead of playing the video.

I'm aware (and a proud owner) of AirParrot, but it's a "whatever's on your screen" type of thing, which gets a little choppy, and the audio is often not properly synced.

Are there any ways, with a Mac and Apple TV, to send a live video stream over AirPlay, or to open it on my Apple TV?

Answer (score 1):

Well as you said with AirParrot (which btw is also great for Windows users) you can extend your display to a "**Specific App…**" thus QuickTime/VLC/MplayerX. To avoid choppy video you should use Ethernet cable…
I don't know what can be done and how Mavericks reacts with the second display feature while changing desktop… But I believe you have the same kind of lags.

Air Video HD allows from local device to AppleTV streams : http://www.inmethod.com/airvideohd/index.html
It should not be to complicated to route your favorite remote server on a local IP address /etc/hosts or something like that …

The alternative that would work for AppleTV v2 and v3 (that last one not being jail braked) is to emulate the "Trailers" service to be able to stream from "PlexConnect" :
— http://gigaom.com/2013/06/04/plex-apple-tv-plexconnect/
— http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1s09hRaWm4

Answer (score 0):

i like Well as you said with AirParrot (which btw is also great for Windows users) you can extend your display to a "Specific App…" thus QuickTime/VLC/MplayerX. To avoid choppy video you should use Ethernet cable… I don't know what can be done and how Mavericks reacts with the second display feature while changing desktop… But I believe you have the same kind of lags